# How can I correctly count the number of the neighboring cells for each cell in the image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, image-segmentation

Please, I'd like to compute the percentage of hexagonal cells (e.g., the number of cells having 6 neighbors cells/ total number of cells) in a binary image and produce a colored coded image as shown below.

I've tried the python code below but I didn't get the correct output. For example, as you can see that the red cells in the binary image have either, 4,5,6, or 7 neighbors cells, but it wrongly calculated as they have 3,4 and 6 neighbors.

An example of a binary image and its output is attached.

```
import sys
import json
import cv2
import os
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import measurements, morphology
from skimage import measure
import time


def cells_measurements(path, orig_image, color="yellow", size=3, 
    pixel_sz=0.00104167):
    size = int(size)
    im = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    _, im = cv2.threshold(im, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    labeled_image, num_of_cells = measurements.label(255 - im)
    props = measure.regionprops(labeled_image)
     number_of_cells = len(props)

  colored_image = np.pad(cv2.cvtColor(~im, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), ((1, 1),(1, 1), (0, 0,)), mode='constant',constant_values=0)

  colors = [[0, 0, 128], [0, 0, 255], [0, 128, 255], [0, 255, 255],[128,255, 128], [255, 255, 0], [255, 128, 0],[255, 0, 0]]

   count_hex = 0
   labels = np.unique(labeled_image)
   for l in labels[1:]:
       i_temp = (labeled_image == l).astype(float) * 255
       i_temp = cv2.dilate(i_temp, np.ones((3, 3)), iterations=2) - i_temp
       i_temp2 = np.copy(labeled_image)
       i_temp2[i_temp == 0.] = 0
       adjacent = len(np.unique(i_temp2)) - 1
       if adjacent == 6:
          count_hex += 1
     cv2.floodFill(colored_image, None, (int(cell_center_all[l - 1][1]), 
     int(cell_center_all[l - 1][0])), colors[min(adjacent, 7)])

       hexagonal_cells = (count_hex / num_of_cells) * 100

     colored_image = np.pad(colored_image, ((0, 0), (0, 75), (0, 0)), 
    'constant', constant_values=255)
       for i in range(8):
           step = colored_image.shape[0] // 8
           colored_image[i * step:+(i + 1) * step, -60:-35] = colors[7 - i]
           colored_image[i * step, -60:-35] = 0
           colored_image[(i + 1) * step, -60:-35] = 0
           colored_image[i * step:(i + 1) * step, -60] = 0
           colored_image[i * step:(i + 1) * step, -35] = 0
           cv2.putText(colored_image, str(7 - i), (colored_image.shape[1] - 
           30, 5 + i * step + step // 2), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, 0)

   color_path = 'Labeled Images/' + fn + "_color.png"
   cv2.imwrite(color_path, colored_image)

  Auto_Cells_Pleomorphism = []

  Mask_Path = 'generated_samples_masks/'
  Original_img_path = 'TestingSet/enhanced_imgs/'
  # please note that the "mask" image is the result of the segmentation 
  algorithm which I will provide today

  # Loop over images
  for i in range(1, 640):
      filename = str(i) + '.png'
      print(filename)
      Masks_Path = os.path.join(Mask_Path, filename)
      Original_image = os.path.join(Original_img_path, filename)
      [hexagonal_cells] = cells_measurements(Masks_Path, Original_image, 
      color="yellow", size=3) 

  Auto_Cells_Pleomorphism.append(round(hexagonal_cells))
```

[image: The binary image]

As you can see that the binary image has some blurred edges. How can I improve their visibility?

[image: Colored coded image]

Comment: Your code has an unmatched `'` character (are where the syntax highlighting goes wrong), his will not run. Is this exactly the same code you ran? Please copy-paste code you actually ran into your question!

Comment: What do you mean by “ the binary image has some blurred edges”? A binary image has only two different values, there cannot be any blurring. The image you show there is not binary.

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/

Comment: Dear Cris Luengo thank you for your help, indeed this is the same code that I'm running.

Comment: I meant the foggy edges.

Comment: @Alaa-Alwaisy `print(len(img.shape))` where img is the name of the image you read, so you can adapt this name depending on your code, my point is that: if it prints 3 then it's color image, if it prints 2 then either binary or grayscale, to check the type you have to check the unique values using implemented numpy function called [unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) just print the result of unique function to see if the result is grayscale or binary.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to use the Watershed algorithm for segmentation.

Read about it here:

https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/02/watershed-opencv/

There are [many other segmentation algorithms](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html) that you could look at
to see if anything works better (e.g. [Felsenszwalb's algorithm](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.felzenszwalb)). [Here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_segmentations.html) is a simple comparison of three algorithms, you could easily extend this example to see how they compare on your dataset.

Once you have the contours of all elements (polygons) you can use them
to create a "complete map" (identify all cells and their neighbours, no holes, no unknown elements) to make sure you are not missing any cells. You could call this the *topology* of your cells.

One thing that might help is to create "clearer" polygons from the once returned by the watershed algorithm.

You might have to

- merge nodes if they are very close
- connect edges if the angles at their connection is about 0 °

This is called "fixing, repairing, simplifying a mesh". 
It is a topic on its own, and there are of course tools for that.
You can read about Python-related projects 
[here](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_local_mesh_cleanup.html), 
[here](https://pypi.org/project/pymeshfix/) or
[here](https://pypi.org/project/trimesh/).

Once this is finished you just count the edges, create a list of all neighbouring cells and cross-check that all neighbours are detected.

This algorithm is not something that will work out of the box, 
you will have to improve and tweak it until it works.

Comment: Good answer. Also, look at Felzenszwalb and Huttenlocher in skimage

Comment: I'm not looking from a new segmentation approach, I need to fix the code above and make it works on that binary image. I'm new to the python and I'm not sure if the code read this image as a binary image or not.

Comment: The blurry edges in the image can probably be improved by a morphological operation. https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/auto_examples/xx_applications/plot_morphology.html   Take a look at Dilation or Closing. Between the operations you might have to work with a threshold to strengthen the boundaries, then repeat.